# Referencing a value in a list box on a ms access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form `FRMSOCIALGRAPH`.  In the form I have a subform  `FrmSGSystems`. 
On the subform I have a list box - Systemlist (1 column)-  with multiple values. On clicking of a value I would like a query to run specific to the value on the list box. Plan was to pass a value onto the main form in a Txtbox, and then use the value of the Txtbox in my query criteria.

I cannot get the reference from the list box though into the Txt box.
The code that I have is:

```
Me!SystemLookup = Forms.frmsocialgraph.FrmSGSystems.Form.Systemlist.Column( _
    0, Me.Systemlist.ListIndex)
```

I suspect that it is something to do with how I reference my forms and sub forms. If anyone is able to assist I would appreciate it.

First error message is that it cant find the field 
     `SYSTEMLOOKUP` which is the text box on  on my form `FRMSOCIALGRAPH` and I want to move the value into the text box.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it has only one column, you can use its `Value` property. However you don't have to copy the value to a textbox in order to use it your query.

To access the value from your query:

```
Forms!MainForm!SubForm.Form!ControlName
```

In your case:

```
Forms!frmsocialgraph!FrmSGSystems.Form!Systemlist
```

You can also set the above as a parameter to the query exactly as shown above and define its data-type.

Comment: Hi,  so when I did your suggestion, it worked perfectly - and I picked up the value. However, I then moved the form into a navigation form `01 Main` and changed the code to `Private Sub Systemlist_Click()

Forms![01 main]!frmsocialgraph!SystemLookup = Forms.[01 main].frmsocialgraph.FrmSGSystems.Form.Systemlist.Column(0, Me.Systemlist.ListIndex)
 DoCmd.OpenQuery "QrySocialGraph_systems"
End Sub`    I now get object not supported.  Any ideas as to why. Thank you

Comment: Try changing `.Column(0, Me.Systemlist.ListIndex) ` to `.Value`. Also if the method resides within the form's code file, you don't need to use `Forms![01 main]` but `Me`. `Me` refers to form where the code resides.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Me.Parent!Textboxid.value = Me.Systemlist.Column(0, Me.Systemlist.ListIndex)
```

from your sub-form